# Buildroot package dependents

Tags: dependencies, buildroot

On Buildroot, given a package **P**, I'm trying to know, textually, all the packages that depend on **P**.

I already know about `make <pgk>-graph-depends` command, but this command shows what packages **P** depends, but I want to know who depends on **P**.

I'm using Buildroot version 2015-08.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, just do a full dependency graph (`make graph-depends`) and follow the arrows that point to package P. The `dot` file is a text file and can easily be parsed. Of course, that only gives you the reverse dependencies of P enabled in your current configuration, and not all possible reverse dependencies of P.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check dependencies of all packages, not just the ones you have selected in the configuration, you can use `make printvars`. For example, if you want to find all the packages that need openssl, you can do:

```
make printvars | \
    grep openssl | \
    sed -n '/\(.*\)_FINAL_ALL_DEPENDENCIES=.*/s//\1/p'
```

Note that this still depends on your configuration, because optional dependencies will only be included if the package is actually selected.

Answer (score 0):

For reverse dependencies use `make <pgk>-graph-rdepends` to create a graph.

If you want to just display the list of dependencies and reverse dependencies then you can use `make <pgk>-show-depends` and `make <pgk>-show-rdepends` for first order dependencies.

For all direct and indirect dependencies use `make <pgk>-show-recursive-depends` and `make <pgk>-show-recursive-rdepends`